# Get html value starting at specific element

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html code

```
<div id="text">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p id="selected">How are you?</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

When I do this

```
$('#text').html()
```

I'll get this value:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p id="selected">How are you?</p>
<p>Hey</p>
```

Is any way to get html value starting at line with `id="selected"`?

**Example**

I want to do something like this

```
$('#text').html({from: '#selected'})
```

and as result will get

```
<p id="selected">How are you?</p>
<p>Hey</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get #selected and all next siblings and combine their `outerHTML`

```js
var html = $('#selected').nextAll().addBack().map((i, el) => el.outerHTML).get().join('')


$('<pre/>', {
  text: html
}).appendTo('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p id="selected">How are you?</p>
  <p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below,

```
$("#text #selected").nextAll().addBack().get().map(function(elm){
  return elm.outerHTML;
}).join("");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a4v98dr0/)

- `nextAll()` will select all the siblings next to the invoked element.
- `addBack()` will add element on the previous pass to the current
  element collection.